# Iterate over vector (or sequence) and use index and value in conditional

Tags: iteration

I want to go through the values (0 or 1) of an array, then if entry has value `1`, a function is called.  But I also want to keep track on which element I am processing.

```
(defvar selectr [0 1 1 0 0])
```

This is the thing I want to do, want to get value from `yon-recorder` at each array position `i`.  If the value is `1` and depending of current value of `i`, I call `yon-armg` function with some specific argument.

```
(defun yon ()
  "TODO."

  (dotimes (i 5)
    (let ( (j (aref selectr i)) )

      (when (and (equal i 1) (equal j 1))
         (yon-armg 'horz 'on))

      (when (and (equal i 2) (equal j 1))
         (yon-armg 'vert 'on))

      (when (and (equal i 3) (equal j 1))
         (yon-armg 'ivy 'on)) )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seq-do-indexed` is the function to use here. Here is an example of its usage:

```lisp
(let ((selectr [0 1 1 0 0]))
  (seq-do-indexed (lambda (e i)
                     (print (append (list e i)
                                    (when (eq e 1)
                                      (pcase i
                                        (1 'horz)
                                        (2 'vert)
                                        (3 'ivy))))))
                    selectr))
```

You can modify it to your needs.

Comment: The one where you used `cons` cells looked better.

Comment: I agree, but it 'suggests' that in the conditions both the value and the index may vary, while you mention that in any case the element's value should be 1. So this version 'expresses' the logic better. Of course, when using this you can remove the `print` and the `append`, so this one looks good also...

Comment: Right.  Simply thought that having the more general one would be more useful to other readers.

Comment: That's a good point. But it would not be the best answer to the question (it would provide a more 'cumbersome' solution). Also, inventive/playful readers will easily apply/come up with such modifications themselves. However, feel free to edit the answer (and add the alternative solution) to make it more useful (but you should build up credits for that, and not switch account/username continuously)

Answer (score 0):

In your application `yon` you do not really use the numeric indexes
but actually the symbols `horz`, `vert` and `ivy`.

In that case [`cl-mapc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Mapping-over-Sequences.html#index-cl_002dmapc) is an alternative to  [`seq-do-indexed`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74418/2370).

It maps a function over multiple sequences.

One sequence can be the sequence of selectors and the other one the indexing symbols.

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun yon-armg (d on)
  "TODO."
  (message "(yon-armg %s %s)" d on))

(defun yon (selectr)
  "TODO."
  (cl-mapc (lambda (d e)
               (when (and d (eq e 1))
                 (yon-armg d 'on)))
             '(nil horz vert ivy)
             selectr))

(yon [0 1 1 0 0])
```